# Unable to read files after synchronization of my Synology NAS to distant VPS with rsync

Tags: synchronization, rsync, vps, nas, synology

I used rsync to sync my Synology NAS with a distant VPS. The synchronization went well, but I don't have the files in the same state. I explain myself:
I have 4 folders (Config, Guard, Control, Pool) and 4 technical files.
In "Pool", I've got a folder named "0" (the biggest), and three others (bucketID.counter.2, chuck_index, file_pool). The "0" folder contains other folders "0", "1", "2", etc. and these folders contain a lot of files named "[NUMBER].index.2" and "[INDEX].bucket.2".

My goal is to have the same files as on my NAS, not just an unreadable backup.

My VPS is a Debian Jessie, if this information is relevant.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I presume the file names you listed are the ones on the destination, not the source? rsync does not do that; you must have used something else, or else haven't synced what you thought you did?

Comment: Yes, the names are the names of the destination. I used Hyperbackup of Synology, which uses rsync. Now that you mention it, I suppose Synology added a layer encrypting the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you want to sync, you have to choose the option at the bottom of the choices, not "rsync" (althought you're using rsync... yes, I know...)